# How to find dim of linear subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In $\mathbb{R}^5$ we have linear subspace $X$ such $\dim(X)=3$ and let $V=\{A\in \mathbb{R}^{5,4} : \operatorname{im}(A)\subset X\}$. I need to find $\dim(V)$. If we knew that result doesn't depend on choice of $X$ we could choose $X = \operatorname{span}(\{ [1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0]\})$ and easily show that $\dim(V) = (5-3)\cdot4=8$. How to do it in general?

Comment: You're wrong: the answer should be 
$$
\dim V = 3 \times 4 = 12
$$
In particular, the matrices which have a $1$ somewhere in the top $3 \times 4$ submatrix and a zero everywhere else form a basis of your space in the case of your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** $V$ may also be characterized as the space of matrices whose columns are in $X$.